# How to get current value : Angular

Tags: angular

**Hi,**  I need to display Toast notification in my View once the number of notification increased (means once new data entered into database).

I tried with this function , now I'm stuck how can I get the current number of notifications.

**This in my function(ts file):**

public getnotificationsByReceiver(): void {

```
this.notificationService.getNotificationsByReceiver().subscribe(
  (response: Notification[]) => {
    this.notifications = response;

    this.notifications.forEach(notification => {

      if (notification[2] == "PENDING") {
        this.numberNotification = this.numberNotification + 1;
       
      }

    },
   
    );
 
    if (this.numberNotification > this.numberNotification) {
      this.messageServcie.add({
        severity: 'success',
        summary: 'Success',
        detail: 'New  Notification From Patient  retrieved'
      })
   }

  },
  (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(error);
    this.messageServcie.add({
      severity: 'error',
      summary: 'Error',
      detail: 'Unable to get data'
    })
   
  }
)
```

}

Here i need to get the current value to compare it with the new to display notification once the number increased :

```
  if (this.numberNotification > this.numberNotification) {
          this.messageServcie.add({
            severity: 'success',
            summary: 'Success',
            detail: 'New  Notification From Patient  retrieved'
          })
```

please i'm stuck into it can't find the solution to resolve this problem, Any help please!

Current output: I have my arrays to display, and the number of arrays(notification number here) :

[image]

I need to display Toast once the number of notification decreased here the number of notification is 26 once is 27 i need to display toast that there are new notification.

Comment: please send us your current output and the output desired if possible the input here the data structure of what you get in your observable

Comment: I updated the post can u check it please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm correct you wanna do something, here use a toas represented by messageService.add() when their is an higher number of notification.
If it's that this could do the trick

```
// create in your component isInit: boolean = false;
this.notificationService.getNotificationsByReceiver().subscribe(
  (response: Notification[]) => {
    this.notifications = response; // we update the array
    let numberOfNotification: number = 0;
    this.notifications.forEach(notification => { // we get the length of pending notifications

      if (notification[2] === "PENDING") {
        numberOfNotifications += 1;
      }

    });
    if (numberOfNotifaction > this.numberNotification && this.isInit) {
      this.messageServcie.add({
        severity: 'success',
        summary: 'Success',
        detail: 'New  Notification From Patient  retrieved'
      })
   }
   this.numberNotification = numberOfNotification; // we update the old count
   this.isInit = true;

  },
  (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(error);
    this.messageServcie.add({
      severity: 'error',
      summary: 'Error',
      detail: 'Unable to get data'
    })
```

the probleme was that on your old code you had `if (this.numberNotification > this.numberNotification)` and this doesn't make any sense because you compare the same thing and you didn't reset this number when you get new data you just increment it

You should add an attribute isInit to avoid creating a toast when you get data the first time

Comment: thnx a lot, it works but please, i had this problem, the toast is displayed  even if I refresh the page without increasing the data ? have u any idea please ?

Comment: I think you get default data (by the way add a check for zero value just to be sure) so I recommande to create a this.isInit: boolean = false in your component and then make it true in your subscribe (at the end) and replace this if     if (numberOfNotifaction > this.numberNotification)

by this one 

 if (numberOfNotifaction > this.numberNotification && this.isInit)

with this you will get data one time and then new data will trigger your toast @lili

Comment: do you want me to edit the answer to show you ?

Comment: @lili done don't forget to add isInit in your component ;)